# Where should I ask this question about finding a research article?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I cannot find this article *the beneficial effects of bacterial infections on host resistance to cancer :end results in 449 cases, HC Nauts, 1980, Cancer Research Institute* on the internet, and I am seeking help from others. Where (which Stack Exchange) should I ask this type of question?

And yes, I know it's stupid.

Comment: http://www.secondopinionfilm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Read_a_1982_published_paper_on_Coleys_Toxins.pdf - That took me 20 seconds..

Comment: @Mithrandir That paper has a different title ... the paper the OP is looking for is reference 4 in the link you provided.

Comment: You should ask at http://www.cancerresearch.org/ dot stackexchange dot com

Answer (score 6):

There is nowhere on the network of sites that this is a good question.

SE doesn't want to be a link database. We focus on high quality questions and answers. Your question and its answer won't add any knowledge.